# What was Prophet Muhammad's (PBUH) routine in i'tikaf?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, ramadan

What did our beloved Prophet Muhammad PBUH do all day during his I'tikaf?

Answer (score 2):

The Prophet (pbuh) used to perform Itikaf in Ramadan, especially the last ten days of Ramadan.

> Narrated 'Aisha:
>
> (the wife of the Prophet) The Prophet used to practice Itikaf in the
>   last ten days of Ramadan till he died and then his wives used to
>   practice Itikaf after him. (https://muflihun.com/bukhari/33/243)

However, the Prophet (pbuh) performed Itikaf for 20 days on the year of his death.

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> The Prophet used to perform Itikaf every year in the month of Ramadan
>   for ten days, and when it was the year of his death, he stayed in
>   Itikaf for twenty days. (https://muflihun.com/bukhari/33/260)

Moreover, the Prophet (pbuh) performed Itikaf in the last ten days of Shawwal when he was not able to perform it in Ramadan.

> Narrated 'Amra bint 'Abdur-Rahman from 'Aisha:
>
> Allah's Apostle used to practice Itikaf every year in the month of
>   Ramadan. And after offering the morning prayer, he used to enter the
>   place of his Itikaf. 'Aisha asked his permission to let her practice
>   Itikaf and he allowed her, and so she pitched a tent in the mosque.
>   When Hafsa heard of that, she also pitched a tent (for herself), and
>   when Zainab heard of that, she too pitched another tent. When, in the
>   morning, Allah's Apostle had finished the morning prayer, he saw four
>   tents and asked, "What is this?" He was informed about it. He then
>   said, "What made them do this? Is it righteousness? Remove the tents,
>   for I do not want to see them." So, the tents were removed. **The
>   Prophet did not perform Itikaf that year in the month of Ramadan, but
>   did it in the last ten days of Shawwal.**
>   (https://muflihun.com/bukhari/33/257)

As for the question--What did the Prophet (pbuh) do in Itikaf?---, it is written below:

> Literally, itikaf means waiting somewhere and stopping. Whether good
>   or bad, it means binding the soul to something. Religiously, it refers
>   to a Muslim abandoning outside relations and cares and **staying in a
>   mosque for some time with the purpose of worship**. In the 187th verse
>   of Chapter al-Baqarah of the Qur'an, it is stated: “...do not
>   associate in intimacy with them (your wives) during the period when
>   you are in retreat in the mosques...”; so itikaf is a type of worship
>   which is present both in the Qur'an and in the Sunnah (the practice of
>   the Prophet). (https://questionsonislam.com/article/itikaf-prophet)
>
> When Allah's Messenger, peace and blessings upon him, wanted to
>   perform itikaf, his bed or his bedstead on which he slept would be
>   placed in front of or behind the Pillar of Repentance (Abu Lubaba),
>   which was in the mosque. (Ibn-i Majah, Siyam: 61) Narrated 'Aisha:
>   (the wife of the Prophet) Allah's Apostle used to let his head in (the
>   house) while he was in the mosque and I would comb and oil his hair.
>   **When in Itikaf he used not to enter the house except for a need.**
>   (https://muflihun.com/bukhari/33/246)

So Itikaf is mainly worshipping Allah alone and to remember him and to do righteousness. In short, a Muslim is supposed to pray salat (e.g. Nafl salat), recite Quran, make Du'a, etc in the Mosque.

> One may perform a “Nafil” type of “itikaf” in a Masjid for one or two
>   days, or even for an hour according to Imam Shafi, Imam Yusuf, and
>   Imam Muhammad. (https://al-talib.org/what-is-itikaf/)

I hope you got the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful input, with sources.